# Проблема с многомерными массивами в PHP

Tags: массивы, post, php

Помогите, пожалуйста, с работой с многомерным массивом в PHP.
Имеется двумерный массив типа **$array[%номер строки%][%индекс элемента в строке%]** который передан методом POST скрипту. В результате заполнения формы скрипт получает массив
в переменную **$array** таким образом:
**$array=$_POST['array']** содержание массива печатается функцией **print_r($array)**,
а простой элемент не могу получить **echo $array[1]['name']** ничего не печатает,
проверил элемент с функцией **isset($array)** - возвратила  **false**. Почему не могу получить значения по индексам, хотя распечатка функцией **print_r($array)** проходит.

**Добавлено из комментария.**

```
/* Часть 
        моего 
              массива */

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            ['id_order'] => 1
            ['name'] => Principala
            ['title'] => 
            ['source'] => common.php
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ['id_order'] => 2
            ['name'] => Activități
            ['title'] => 
            ['source'] => common.php
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            ['id_order'] => 3
            ['name'] => Dansuri
            ['title'] => 
            ['source'] => 
        )
)
```

Comment: Распечатку в студию!))

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: А оно не должно быть `echo $array[1]->['name']`?

Comment: @alexlz, нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну и в чем проблема-то?

Это если просто для примера чтобы вывелись первые 2 строки.

```
$array=$_POST['array'];
//первая строка
echo $array[0]['id_order']."<br />\n";
echo $array[0]['name']."<br />\n";
echo $array[0]['title']."<br />\n";
echo $array[0]['source']."<br />\n";

//вторая строка
echo $array[1]['id_order']."<br />\n";
echo $array[1]['name']."<br />\n";
echo $array[1]['title']."<br />\n";
echo $array[1]['source']."<br />\n";
```

Можно это все в цикле сделать.

Можно использовать **foreach ()** или **for ()** кто с чем больше дружит.

```
// выбрали цикл
     {
      echo "id_order=".$array[$i]['id_order']." name=".$array[$i]['name']." title="..$array[$i]['title']." source=".$array[$i]['source']."<br />\n";
     }
```

есть вопросы пиши в скайп, пообщаемся.